# Worklight ANT with shell component

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an applciation that uses the shell and inner applications.
There is an ant command to build the applications but no command to build 
the shell component.  Is there something i missed in the docs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no Ant command to build the Shell component. This can only be done in Eclipse.

We have this in our tracking system as a feature request. 
Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the wlshell file it looks like it just might be a zip of the components/project folder.  Could i just zip that folder up and call it wlshell?